# How to understand this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I do not say all, **for when the appeal is to universal suffrage unanimity is not to be hoped**.
>
> — [*Mathematical Creation*, H. Poincaré (1913), translated to English by George Bruce Halsted (2012)](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/39713/39713-h/39713-h.htm)

I do not understand the sentence after the comma.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. That sentence is quoted from Poincare's well-known paper Mathematical Creation.

Comment: Do you understand anything about it? Do you have any specific questions or ideas about the meaning, even if it's just a guess?

Comment: As an aside: it's interesting that it's a translation (from French, I presume), and one that was done by a mathematician and not a linguist. It's arguable that the word "_for_" should be at the end. One does not "_hope unanimity_"; one "_hopes **for** unanimity_". Perhaps Halsted was deterred from adding that final word by fear of being (unfairly) criticized for ending with a preposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quoted sentence in iself seems hard to understand, but it becomes clear when the whole paragraph is analysed:

> This has long been appreciated, and some time back the journal called
>   L'enseignement mathématique, edited by Laisant and Fehr, began an
>   investigation of the mental habits and methods of work of different
>   mathematicians. I had finished the main outlines of this article when
>   the results of that inquiry were published, so I have hardly been able
>   to utilize them and shall confine myself to saying that the majority
>   of witnesses confirm my conclusions; I do not say all, for when the
>   appeal is to universal suffrage unanimity is not to be hoped.

The meaning is:

> I do not say that all witnesses confirm my conclusions, because, when
>   an entire population (or entire scientific community) is asked for
>   opinion concerning some particular question, it is only natural that
>   different members of that community will provide different (not
>   unanimous) answers.

To *appeal to universal suffrage* means to use [the concept of universal suffrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_suffrage) as the key principle according to which the opinion of a population should be consulted. The concept calls for asking each member of the population what his/her opinion is - usually during elections.

Usually we *appeal* to a court or a judge or some other higher authority, like a dad or mom or uncle Bob, but we may also *appeal* to an abstract concept, meaning, to take it as a standard in approaching a particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence portion after the comma intends to state that when there is an expectation from a large population, the same answer is not to be expected from each and every member in the population. 

In simpler terms, when you call for a public opinion, you cannot expect that everyone will provide the same answer.

Comment: Much appreciated, Ankur